# ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s). Type "SETX /?" for usage

Tags: javascript, windows, github, electron

I am using Windows 10. In CMD, I tried to execute the following command in my electron project:

```
setx GH_TOKEN "ghp_B3kYZy7OibM1Rka4Y3jLSiBUlvtSS717FhvE" npm run publish
```

And I got this error:

```
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s).
Type "SETX /?" for usage.
```

The following code is the part of content of the **Package.json** file:

```
"scripts": {
    "publish": "electron-builder build -w -p onTagOrDraft"
  }
```

In the tutorial I am watching, this command is entered in the Mac operating system as follows, where it works properly:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
setx GH_TOKEN "ghp_B3kYZy7OibM1Rka4Y3jLSiBUlvtSS717FhvE" && npm run publish
```

The `&&` are necessary because there are two commands. Without the `&&`, the `npm run publish` will be passed as arguments to `SETX`

Comment: At line:1 char:58
+ setx GH_TOKEN "ghp_B3kYZy7OibM1Rka4Y3jLSiBUlvtSS717FhvE" &&  npm run  ...
+                                                          ~~
The token '&&' is not a valid statement separator in this version.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidEndOfLine

Comment: I just tested it in CMD as per your question. It works. In what environment are you running this? Powershell?

Comment: Thank you very much, this command in CMD worked correctly. I tested your command in Power Shell and noticed that I have to use the following syntax:
(command1) -and (command2)

Answer (score 3):

This error also occurs if the environment variable you're setting contains one or more spaces.

In this case, you may avoid the problem by enclosing the value in double quotes. Unlike `SET`, which would take the quotes to be part of the value, `SETX` excludes the quotes from your stored value.

The differences in space and quote handling by `SET` and `SETX` are shown in the examples below.

**For `SET` with spaces**, quotes are not needed (and if included, become part of the value):

```
Set a value                              View the value                              
-----------------------------            -----------------------------
C:\TEMP>set MYVAR=some value             C:\TEMP>set MY
                                         MYVAR=some value

C:\TEMP>set MYVAR="some value"           C:\TEMP>set MY
                                         MYVAR="some value"
```

**For `SETX` with spaces**, quotes *are* needed (and do *not* become part of the value):

```
Set a value                              View the value in a new window                      
-----------------------------            -----------------------------
C:\TEMP>SETX MYVAR some value
ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more than '2' time(s).
Type "SETX /?" for usage.

C:\TEMP>SETX MYVAR "some value"          C:\TEMP>set MY
SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.      MYVAR=some value
```